# Simple pendulum animation using Lagrangian, problems with Graphics[]

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, warning-messages, physics

I am trying to create some animations of classical mechanical systems in mathematica by using Lagrangians. I wanted to start off by doing the simple pendulum that is visually just a line, then adding more complex stuff like springs and moving supports. I am very new to mathematica but I have some experience with scheme and C. Any time I try to put `{qx[t],qy[t]}` as a 2-vector (in ParametricPlot or any Graphics environment) I get errors about wrongly sized arrays, but I tried to `Join` them and I still get errors. Could someone tell me what is wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
x[t_] = Sin [\[Theta][t]]
y[t_] = Cos[\[Theta][t]]

L = Simplify[(1/2) ((D[x[t], t])^2 + (D[y[t], t])^2) - 9.81*y[t]]

ELeqn = Simplify[D[L, \[Theta][t]] == D[D[L, D[\[Theta][t], t]], t]]

sol = NDSolve[{ELeqn , \[Theta][0] == Pi/4, \[Theta]'[0] == 
    0}, \[Theta][t], {t, 0, 10}]

qx[t_] = (x[t] /. sol)
qy[t_] = (y[t] /. sol)
framelist = Table[
   Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, {qx[t], qy[t]}}]}], {t, 0, 10, .1}];
ListAnimate[framelist]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need something more like:

```
x[t_] = Sin[\[Theta][t]]
y[t_] = Cos[\[Theta][t]]

L = Simplify[(1/2) ((D[x[t], t])^2 + (D[y[t], t])^2) - 9.81*y[t]]

ELeqn = Simplify[D[L, \[Theta][t]] == D[D[L, D[\[Theta][t], t]], t]]

sol = First@NDSolve[{ELeqn, \[Theta][0] == Pi/4, \[Theta]'[0] == 
    0}, \[Theta][t], {t, 0, 10}]

qx = (\[Theta][t] /. sol)
qy = (\[Theta][t] /. sol)
framelist = Table[Graphics[{
     Line[{{0, 0}, {Sin@qx, Cos@qy}}]
     },
    PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
    ], {t, 0, 10, .1}];
ListAnimate[framelist]
```

The main changes I made:

- `sol` returns something that looks like `{{theta(t) -> InterpolatingFunction[](t)}}`. This extra set of curly braces causes issues, so I added `First@NDSolve...` to get rid of it.
- Since it returns a function of $\theta$, `x[t]/.sol` and `y[t]/.sol` won't match the pattern and will not be replaced. They need to be `theta[t]/.sol` in order to match.
- I removed the `[t_]` from `qx` and `qy` as they're not necessary since `sol` already has `(t)` at the end.
- I added `Sin` and `Cos` to the positions of the lines since `sol` contains the angle, not the Cartesian position.
- I added a `PlotRange` to the `Graphics` so that it doesn't try to resize the graphic each time.

[image: Pendulum animation.]

Comment: Thank you, I was really confused about the syntax and such and why things were not working. This is very helpful.

Comment: @inquisitivelearner Yes, for sure. For an early project, there are lots of things that are easy to get tripped up on when combining `NDSolve` along with replacements, plotting, animating, and various symbols. You were really close on your own!

Comment: How would one do replacement rules, but with function composition? Such as having ```qx``` be x, but solved for the boundary conditions in NDsolve and all in terms of t?

Comment: @inquisitivelearner Do you mean having NDSolve return x and y instead of $\theta$? If so, I'm not completely sure how to do that. I've always solved pendulum problems in $\theta$.

Comment: Nevermind, figured out what I was talking about. Thanks for the help, friend.